# How to Hide an ID from an URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, routes

net 4 and c# with Routing.

I would like to know how to pass a value in a DataToken from GetRouteUrl (or another ways).

My aim is to crete a Url like "mysite.com/category-title"
and passing (hiding from the URL the `categoryId`) but in the destination page I would like retrieve the hidden `categoryId` for filtering.

At the moment I try to accomplish this using DataTokens, without result.

My questions:

- How to hide an Id in the Url generated by Routing and passing hidden an Id?
- Is it my approach the right way (using DataTokens)? Any better idea (please provide me a sample of code)

Thanks for your time on this.

```
<asp:HyperLink runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Title") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# GetRouteUrl( new { Title = Eval("Title") }) %>'></asp:HyperLink>
```

---

```
   public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
            // Ex: mysite.com/category-title/
        routes.MapRouteCategoryView("myRouteName", "{Title}");
    }
```

---

I would

```
public static void MapRouteCategoryView(this RouteCollection routes, string name, string url)
        {
            // Page Handler map filter to physical path.
            PageRouteHandler handler = new PageRouteHandler("~/Cms/FrontEndCms/CategoryView.aspx");
            // Create the Route.
            CustomRoute myRoute = new CustomRoute(url, handler);
            // Setting the Route.
            //myRoute.Constraints = new RouteValueDictionary { { "CategoryId", @"\d+" } }; // Only valid Int for Id.
            myRoute.DataTokens = new RouteValueDictionary { { "RouteName", name } };
            // Add the Route to RouteCollection.
            routes.Add(myRoute);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try just encrypting the categoryID in the QueryString.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the latest version of IIS you can use the URL Rewrite module.

I have usually done something similar to this by using the URL to get the category (or page in my case) by the querystring value the route maps to and then search the database by the route (or path).

Hope this helps.

Craig

Comment: Hi i need to implement is using Asp.net Routing and not Rewrite module nay ideas?

Comment: no sorry I have very limited exposure to routing - would be interested to see the resolution though :S